# How do I delete values in MySQL according to primary key on another table

Tags: mysql

Example my db structure `olddb` & `newdb`

`newdb`

```
ID email           Name
-----------------------
1  john@yahoo.com  John
2  peter@yahoo.com Peter
```

`olddb`

```
ID email           
-------------------
1  john@yahoo.com  
2  peter@yahoo.com 
3  rambo@hello.com
4  super@duper.com
```

Now I want compare `olddb` with `newdb` and delete from `olddb` which email doesn't have email in `newdb`

Let me know

```
DELETE FROM olddb, newdb
USING olddb
    INNER JOIN newdb USING(email) 
WHERE olddb.email <> newdb.email
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you a list of all emails from `oldtbl` which are not on `newtbl`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM oldtbl
WHERE id NOT IN (
   SELECT id FROM newtbl
)
```

Note: `oldtbl` and `newtbl` because I found your naming scheme confusing. We are talkind about  *tables*, not *databases*.

To delete those rows on `oldtbl`, just change `SELECT *` with `DELETE`.

Answer (score 1):

DELETE FROM oldb WHERE olddb.email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM newdb);

There are probably other ways to do it, but that will work.